# mmenujs Links are not crawlable and does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance

Tags: javascript, lighthouse, mmenu

Running google lighthouse performance and SEO test on [mmenujs.com](https://mmenujs.com/) (which is using mmenu.js) yields both following errors:
[Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYAV7.png)

[Links are not crawlable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjKMZ.png)

Both errors originate from the **mmenu.js** that I'm using on my typo3 website.
Does anybody know how to solve these issues without removing mmenu.js altogether?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?
I am having the exact same problem, even when I don't have any navbar options in use.